# Is it scaled twice in keras code categorical_crossentropy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I see `categorical_crossentropy` is implemented in Keras as follows:

```
def categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False, axis=-1):
    """Categorical crossentropy between an output tensor and a target tensor.
    # Arguments
        target: A tensor of the same shape as `output`.
        output: A tensor resulting from a softmax
            (unless `from_logits` is True, in which
            case `output` is expected to be the logits).
        from_logits: Boolean, whether `output` is the
            result of a softmax, or is a tensor of logits.
        axis: Int specifying the channels axis. `axis=-1`
            corresponds to data format `channels_last`,
            and `axis=1` corresponds to data format
            `channels_first`.
    # Returns
        Output tensor.
    # Raises
        ValueError: if `axis` is neither -1 nor one of
            the axes of `output`.
    """
    output_dimensions = list(range(len(output.get_shape())))
    if axis != -1 and axis not in output_dimensions:
        raise ValueError(
            '{}{}{}'.format(
                'Unexpected channels axis {}. '.format(axis),
                'Expected to be -1 or one of the axes of `output`, ',
                'which has {} dimensions.'.format(len(output.get_shape()))))
    # Note: tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    # expects logits, Keras expects probabilities.
    if not from_logits:
        # scale preds so that the class probas of each sample sum to 1
        output /= tf.reduce_sum(output, axis, True)
        # manual computation of crossentropy
        _epsilon = _to_tensor(epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
        output = tf.clip_by_value(output, _epsilon, 1. - _epsilon)
        return - tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(output), axis)
```

I don't under stand from

> output_dimensions = list(range(len(output.get_shape())))

to

> output /= tf.reduce_sum(output, axis, True).

I understand Output is probabilities, a tensor resulting from a softmax -> It  mean is scaled preds so that the class probas of each sample sum to 1. Why do they need to scale preds so that the probas class of each sample sum to 1 again? Please explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to make sure that each probability is between 0 and 1, else the cross-entropy computation will be incorrect. Its a way to also prevent user errors when they make (unnormalized) probabilities outside that range.